# Can't override post method UpdateView

Tags: django

I try to override post method of generic.UpdateView to add few forms from other model. Without overriding post it is working fine.

```
class DesktopView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = WeddyUser
    context_object_name = 'weddyuser'
    slug_field = 'username'
    form_class = WeddyuserForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DesktopView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_vendor:
            if 'form' not in context:
                context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET, instance=self.request.user)
            context['vendor'] = Vendor.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        else:
            context['plainuser'] = PlainUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        user = request.user
        if self.kwargs['slug'] == request.user.username:
            if user.is_vendor:
                return render_to_response('user/vendor_edit_profile.html', self.get_context_data(),
                                      RequestContext(request, c))
            return render_to_response('user/user_edit_profile.html', self.get_context_data(),
                                  RequestContext(request, c))
        return HttpResponse(status=404)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        c={}
        c.update(csrf(request))
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print ('ITS WORK')
            form.save()
            return render_to_response('user/vendor_edit_profile.html', self.get_context_data(form=form),
                                      RequestContext(request, c))
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return render_to_response('user/vendor_edit_profile.html', self.get_context_data(form=form),
                                      RequestContext(request, c))
```

Everytime I get invalid form - "required field"

Comment: You aren't passing a required field to your form. We'd need to see your template, `WeddyUser` model, and `Weddyuserform`.

Comment: I passed data to field of form.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be overriding get or post here. In your case, you need to override `form_valid` for the logic in post, and `get_tempmlate` for the logic in get.

Comment: I thought that need to override post, beacause I plan to add one more form from other model..But I try..

Comment: Didn't help. Could you show example overriding form_valid woth two forms?